# Javscript file wont update on localhost (XAMPP)

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio, xampp

I'm currently developing a website with PHP through XAMPP on a local server. Since yesterday I have the problem that every time I change something in my JS code, the code on the frontend doesn't change. I'm writing the code with VisualStudio and use Chrome. Can anyone help me out?
If you have questions you can of course ask them! The problem is difficult to explain I guess. Thanks a lot!!!

I tried deleting the cache and of course refreshing the website and restarting XAMPP

Comment: Sounds like your client side logic (the js code) is cached on the client side. Which would be the standard behavior. You need to _disable_ that by sending http headers. First, obviously, you should check though if that is the case. The browser's console is your friend here, check the networking tab in there.

Comment: Did you take a look at the "Console" tab of your browser developer tools (press F12 in your keyboard)? If you have an error in your javascript code, it will appear there.